# Having trouble instantiating toolkit?

Tags: java, eclipse, instantiation, toolkit

I'm trying to create a `JFrame` with the dimensions of my screen, so I tried to use the statement `Toolkit kit = new Toolkit();` but it turns red and eclipse tells me "cannot instantiate the type Toolkit". So then I tried `Toolkit kit = new Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();` and that didn't work either. Help!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question could be improved with a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE) or the smallest amount of code you can produce that includes all relevant information and demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Also, I believe the issue is that you're not supposed to create toolkits on your own. You're supposed to get the toolkit associated with an existing window using `window.getToolkit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `new`keyword:

```
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

The method  `getDefaultToolkit` is a static method. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit()) for more details.